# Is it possible to create an interactive notepad within batch script that saves users input

Tags: batch-file, interactive, notepad, pause

I'm in the process of creating a mini-game using batch and one of the useful tool ideas was to have an interactive notepad so that users could store information throughout the game and refer back to it later. So far I have created the option to goto a notepad within an In-game pause menu but wasn't sure if it was possible to save results without outputting to new file on the desktop

```
:PauseMenu
    cls
    echo.
    echo         %Alias%
    echo.
    echo Notepad
    echo Stats
    echo Untitled2
    echo Untitled3
    echo Untitled4
    echo Untitled5
    echo Untitled6
    set/p PauseMenu="N, S" 
    IF ["%PauseMenu%"]==["N"] goto Notepad
    IF ["%PauseMenu%"]==["S"] goto Stats
    IF ["%PauseMenu%"]==["N"] goto
    IF ["%PauseMenu%"]==["N"] goto
    IF ["%PauseMenu%"]==["N"] goto
    IF ["%PauseMenu%"]==["N"] goto
    IF ["%PauseMenu%"]==["N"] goto
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

PS is it possible to go back to the previous page from a menu?

Answer (score 1):

Simplicity itself.

First, some renaming may be in order. `notepad` is a supplied utility and `pausemenu` is being used both as a variable and as a label. This is not invalid, but can be a little confusing.

Further, if you are choosing between a set of keys, I'd suggest you investigate `choice`. `choice` has a number of advantages, like it only accepts one character, no `enter` is required and it's not necessary to analyse the entry.

So: revising your code:

```
:p_pausemenu
pause
:PauseMenu
cls
echo.
echo         %Alias%
echo.
echo N Notepad
echo S Stats
echo 1 Untitled2
echo Z Untitled3
echo Q Untitled4
echo J Untitled5
echo X Untitled6
:: Note that the processing of ERRORLEVEL must be in reverse order
choice /c ns1zqjx
if errorlevel 7 goto labelx
if errorlevel 6 goto labelj
if errorlevel 5 goto labelq
if errorlevel 4 goto labelz
if errorlevel 3 goto label1
if errorlevel 2 goto stats
if errorlevel 1 goto unotepad


:unotepad
start "Notes for %alias%" notepad "c:\gamedirectory\%alias%.txt"
goto pausemenu

:stats
:: List your stats here
echo Stats for %alias%
goto p_pausemenu
```

Here, a menu with a number of unimplemented options is presented and the `choice` command (see `choice /?` from the prompt for more options) waits for a choice to be made.

`errorlevel` is set according to the choice made - but since `if errorlevel n` means `if errorlevel is n OR GREATER THAN n` you need to process `errorlevel` in reverse order.

Then each selection is processed. `n` will start a `notepad` instance and load the `alias.txt` file from the game directory, then present the menu again as it returns to `pausemenu`. `s` will show the stats (idk what you need for that) and then return to `p_pausemenu` which will pause and *then* proceed to show the menu when the user signals to do so.

Comment: Apologies for taking quite a while to get back to you, I will check it out and see if it is what im looking for. Appreciate the response thank you.